# hapi joi filter valid value

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js, joi

Is there a way to do the  same

```
var item = new Item(request.payload);
item.tags = _.map(item.tags, function(s){
    return s.trim().toLowerCase();
});
```

in the validation code ?

```
var Joi = require('joi'),
    Tags = Joi.array().min(1).max(3).unique().required();
exports.create = {
   payload: {
    tags: Tags
   }
};
```

Comment: You want to trim and convert the tags to lowercase in the validation field? Please explain your question thoroughly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This validation schema should work:

```
Joi.array().items(Joi.string().trim().lowercase()).unique().min(1).max(3).required();
```